# Wrong file permission when using git pull in a hook

Tags: git, file-permissions, githooks

I have created the following git hook to update my web application when new changes are pushed to the repository

```
#!/bin/sh
#Update the server version to HEAD

echo "Updating webapp..."
unset $(git rev-parse --local-env-vars)
(cd /var/www/webapp && git pull -q)
```

However, if I add new files they get the wrong permissions. They are only readable by the owner and not by the group or by other users. But I need them to be readable by everyone. Locally they have the right permission bits. And even when I run the hook manually from the shell, it works correctly. It only doesn't work when the script is called as a hook.

Any ideas how to fix that?

PS: I am using git 1.7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Git does not store permissions, apart from the executable bit. So, on checkout, files are created with the default permissions, which depend on your [umask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask).

I guess, when you are calling the hook manually, you have a more liberal umask set. You can override the umask with the `umask` shell command. For your purposes, 0022 is probably fine.

Comment: Setting `umask 0022` in our shell script immediately before the git pull worked perfectly. Thanks!