# set folder permissions when deploying cakephp app

Tags: php, git, cakephp, file-permissions, cakephp-2.4

My cakephp app relies on the `app/webroot/img/product_images` directory existing and being writeable.

Right now I make sure the folder exists with a `.empty` file so git will track the empty directory but I have to remember to chown/chmod the folder manually when I clone my repo to a new server.

Is there any way in CakePHP or pure PHP to automatically check and set the permissions for this folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Git changes the permissions on a single file unexplainably](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18457667/6309)", if:

- you set git config --global core.sharedRepository true
- have a default `umask` (set in your profile) compatible with the write you want (like  `0002` for 775)

you should get the right permissions on the elements you are cloning.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing build into to CakePHP, though I guess you could write some code in your `bootstrap.php` to check for and create the directly, but that doesn't solve your permissions problems.

But really you should to look into is automated deployment tools such as [Capistrano](http://www.capistranorb.com/) or [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.7/).

Basically, they allow you to execute commands on a remote server to help you deploy your app. You can specify that one of the commands they execute is to check the existence and file permissions of your `app/webroot/img/product_images` directory.