# How to stop git from changing my files permissions?

Tags: git, github, permissions

After pushing my files from local to remote repository, the permission of my files changes automatically. For example, I created an executable bash script that gives access to user/group/other:

```
ls -lh test1.sh
```

*`-rwxrwxrwx 1 soroush1 soroush1 34 Oct 10  2023 test1.sh`*

Then staged, commited, and pushed it to GitHub:

```
git add test1.sh test1.sh
git commit -m "test permission"
git push origin
```

After pullling the file on another machine, the file permission has changed:

```
git pull origin
ls -lh test1.sh
```

*`-rw-r--r-- 1 soroush2 soroush2 34 Oct 10 16:09 test1.sh`*

I tried some suggestions from other posts to keep the file's original permission, like this one: [Git changes the permissions on a single file unexplainably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16719458/git-changes-the-permissions-on-a-single-file-unexplainably)

I tried

```
git init --shared=0000
git config core.sharedRepository all
```

But still same problem. Does anyone know how to stop git from changing my file permissions?

Above is just an example. There are many executables (and non-executables) in my repository.

Comment: What does `umask` print on the other machine? Besides, you can use `git ls-tree HEAD test1.sh` on both machines to check the tracked permission, which is either `100755` or `100644`. In your case, it should be `100755`.

Comment: Git does not store permissions. Except for a single bit: "the" executable bit (and, fun fact, it uses several bytes to store just this one bit). There are plenty of duplicates on SO that explain how you can (and have to) work around it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+preserve+file+permissions

Comment: @ElpieKay `umask` prints `0022` on both machines. Also, `git ls-tree HEAD test1.sh` prints `100644` on both machines. Does this mean my git init command ( `git init --shared=0000` ) is not working?

Comment: @Soroush `--shared=0000` is not necessary. If they are `100644` on both machines, it means you didn't track the file as an executable in the first place. You could try `git update-index --chmod=+x test1.sh && git status && git commit` to make sure that an executable test1.sh is tracked.